# TinyMce full page without click on button

Tags: javascript, tinymce

How can I load TinyMCE on full page directly ?

There is a full page button, but i don't want to have to click on for full page...

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be easily done using the [setup configuraton parameter](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3asetup)/onInit-handler and triggering the full page command from there

```
tinyMCE.init({
   ...
   setup : function(ed) {
      ed.onInit.add(function(ed, evt) {
          // do the full page action here
      });
   }
});
```